# Individual specific variables in McFadden's choice model

Tags: stata, logit

From my understanding of McFadden's discrete choice model, individual specific variables such as income should not affect an individual's choice unless interacted with product characteristics.

But in Stata's command `asclogit`, which claims to estimate McFadden's model, allows individual variables without interacting with product characteristics.

I am finding this command bizarre.

Here is my answer to this question : ASCLOGIT DOES not interact the casevars with the product characteristics . It interact the casevars with ALTERNATIVE DUMMIES. This is done behind the scene. If you need interactions with product characteristics, you need to use clogit and manually generate interactions.

Comment: @Nick Cox As an expert in stata, do you have any comments.

Comment: Sorry, no: I've never used this command.

Comment: hmm, I thought the mcfadden's model is quite popular. I am surprised by the lack of discussion of how stata estimates the model .

Comment: I searched the web though.  I didn't find many discussions.

Answer (score 1):

Stata's `asclogit` command formats and handles the interactions behind the scenes, but the interactions between the case-specific variables and the alternatives are performed as part of the analysis with `asclogit`.

The results of `asclogit` are the same as the results of Stata's `clogit` command when the case-specific variables are explicitly interacted with the alternatives.

The `asclogit` command is simply a convenient version of `clogit` and there is nothing "bizarre" about it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's quite helpful. But can you explain more the part where you claim stata asclogit handle the interactions behind the scenes. How would stata know how the interactions be done without instructions. For instance, I could have two product characteristics and two demographic variables.And I only want the demo variables to interact with one characteristics. How is this procedure carried out. If possible, can you show the regression results and explain the meaning of the coefficient output. Your answer now has too many hand waving.

Answer (score 1):

Assume you have the following variables:

`Choice` = Binary outcome var

`ASV1` = First alternative-specific var

`ASV2` = Second alternative-specific var

`CSV1` = First case-specific var

`CSV2` = Second case-specific var

Further assume you have three alternatives per choice set
and that the alternatives are represented by a three-level
multinomial categorical variable named `Alt`.  Also assume
the choice sets variable is a numeric variable named `Choiceset`
and the individual respondents are identified by a variable
named `ID`.

Finally, assume the data set is in long format with one
row of data per alternative and three rows of data representing
one choice set.

For Stata's `asclogit` code for a McFadden's model you
would not need to perform any additional data management steps (after
the data are in long format). The `asclogit` code would simply be:

```
asclogit Choice ASV1 ASV2, case(Choicset) alternatives(Alt) casevars(CSV1 CSV2) vce(cluster ID)
```

For Stata's `clogit` the code for a McFadden's model
would require additional data management steps to create the dummy 
variables for the alternatives and then to create the interaction
terms before running `clogit`.  The code for the data management steps and then `clogit` would be:

```
*Create dummy variables for Alt.
tab Alt, gen(Alt)

*Now create interactions. 
gen Alt2XCSV1 = Alt2*CSV1 
gen Alt3XCSV1 = Alt3*CSV1 
gen Alt2XCSV2 = Alt2*CSV2 
gen Alt3XCSV2 = Alt3*CSV2

* Now run clogit including the interaction terms.   
clogit Choice ASV1 ASV2 Alt2XCSV1 Alt3XCSV1 Alt2XCSV2 Alt3XCSV2 i.Alt2 i.Alt3, group(choiceset) vce(cluster ID)
```

If you replicate these examples with your own data set, you'll see
that the results from both commands are the same and that `asclogit`
is simply a convenient form of `clogit` with explicit interactions.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. To make sure I understand it correctly, adding case variables will force all possible interactions with each alternative variables. But clogit gives you more flexibility.

Comment: After going through the documentation and ado files, here is what I find about asclogit : It DOES not interact the casevars with the product characteristics .  It interact the casevars with ALTERNATIVE DUMMIES.